# Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem (all deviations are broken)

Tags: grubrescue

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in virtual box and my OS is Win10. When I boot, I am getting:

```
error: unknown filesystem.  
grub rescue>
```

I search for solutions and found I need to find my Ubuntu is on which drives and partitions. I tried the following:

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> ls (hd0)
error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos5)
error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)
error: unknown filesystem.
```

It looks like all the deviations are broken. What should I do in this case? Is there any opportunity that I can restore my data and files in my Ubuntu?

Comment: fstab is probably missing or corrupted. try booting to a ubuntu livecd, open terminal and do `sudo su` to switch to root, then mount your rootfs and try to edit /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 0):

I had a 60GB hdd dual booting WinXP and Mate 16.04 perfectly (and painfully slowly). Last week I updated my system to a new 250GB ssd with Windows 7 and Mate 18.

Windows booted just fine, but after the installation of Mate. I got into the exact same situation as you are now.

So, I solved my problem by changing my SSD to a smaller (capacity) model.

I did so because some older partitioning software reported an incorrect SSD size. So, I suspected that I had some BIOS compatibility issue with the bigger SSD.

Now, my system dual boots just fine, with the smaller 128GB SSD.

Hope it helps!
JamMedSyS